# Pass subset argument through a function to subset

Tags: r, subset

I would like to have a function which calls `subset`, and passes on a `subset` argument:

```
df <- data.frame(abc=c("A","A","B","B"),value=1:4)
subset(df,abc=="A")
## works of course:
#  abc value
#1   A     1
#2   A     2

mysubset <- function(df,ssubset)
  subset(df,ssubset)

mysubset(df,abc=="A")
## Throws an error
# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'abc' not found

mysubset2 <- function(df,ssubset)
  subset(df,eval(ssubset))

mysubset2(df,expression(abc=="A"))
## Works, but needs expression
```

I tried with `substitute`, but was not able to find the right combination. How can I get this working?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Evaluation

Comment: James, thanks for the link, it is *very* insightful!

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset

Comment: Updated link to Hadley's page on evaluation and subset: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 answer works, but you can skip the whole deparse/parse cycle by simply using:

```
mysubset <- function(df, p) {
  ps <- substitute(p)
  subset(df, eval(ps))
}
```

Answer (score 14):

You need `eval()` and `parse()` in there too:

```
mysubset <- function(df, ssubset) {
  subset(df, eval(parse(text=ssubset)))
}
mysubset(df, "abc=='A'")
#   abc value
# 1   A     1
# 2   A     2
```

Note that you need to nest quotes, so switch back and forth between `"` and `'` as necessary.

---

Based on your comment, perhaps something like this is also of interest:

```
mysubset <- function(df, ...) {
  ssubset <- deparse(substitute(...))
  subset(df, eval(parse(text = ssubset)))
}
```

USAGE: `mysubset(df, abc=='A')`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know if there is a possibility to do it without quotes?

Comment: Something like this you mean? `mysubset <- function(df, ...) { ssubset <- deparse(substitute(...)); subset(df, eval(parse(text = ssubset))) }`. USAGE: `mysubset(df, abc=='A')`

Comment: Great, thank you, accepting your answer. Would be nice if you can add this possibility also in your main answer.