# Subsetting based on multiple function arguments

Tags: r, function, subset

I'm new to function writing so hopefully the below makes some sense.

I want to create a function which takes some arguments, which will be used to subset a data.frame.  I have searched across the forums and found these Q&As interesting, but haven't been able to answer my question from the discussions:

- [Pass subset argument through a function to subset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880906/pass-subset-argument-through-a-function-to-subset)
- [Why is `[` better than `subset`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset)

The function I want to create will take a df, a column name, and a value to match in the rows of the column name.  Here's my attempt which I can see to be wrong:

```
x <- data.frame("col1"=c("email","search","direct"),
            "col2"=c("direct","email","direct"),
            "col3"=c(10,15,27))

fun <- function(df,col,val) {
  result <- subset(df, col==val)
  return(result)
}
```

I want to pass in the df, x.  A column name, let's say "col2".  A value, let's say "email".  My attempt to do so returns a 0-length df.

```
fun(x,"col2","email")
```

Clearly I'm doing something wrong... can anyone help?

Comment: you should have a read at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset) to learn a bit more about issues with using `subset` inside a function.

Comment: I notice you do not use a lot of spaces in your code, e.g. `function(df,col,etc)` -> `function(df, col, etc)` or `col==val` -> `col == val`. Adding spaces makes your code easier to read, less intimidating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want to do somehting like :

```
df[df[[col_name]] == value,]
```

the function then becomes:

```
fun <- function(df, col_name, value) {
  df[df[[col_name]] == value,]
}
fun(x, 'col2', 'email')
    col1  col2 col3
2 search email   15
```

and if you want to take into account NA values in the logical vector:

```
fun <- function(df, col_name, value) {
  logical_vector = df[[col_name]] == value
  logical_vector[is.na(logical_vector)] = FALSE
  df[logical_vector, drop = FALSE]
}
```

Why your example not works is because `subset` does not look inside the value of `col`. In stead, it will look for a column called `col`. I suspect the `val` parameter is also not correctly parsed. This is one of the reasons not to use `subset` in non-interactive mode, i.e. in anything else than an interactive R console.

Comment: Great - that makes total sense.  Thanks for such a quick response Paul.

Comment: you might want to take care of NAs if you want to mimic `subset` using `[.data.frame`. `subset` drops those row indices for which the logical expression evaluates to NA.

Comment: And you should add `drop = FALSE` in case the user passes in a 1 col df.

Comment: @hadley I also added that improvement.