# Passing on non-standard evaluation arguments to the subset function

Tags: r, subset

I want to use `subset` within another function but to pass on the non-standard evaluation arguments from the top-level function. The following is non-working code, but outlines the idea:

```
foo_1 <- function(x, mysubset) 
{
  # some deparse, substitute etc. magic here ??
  subset(x, subset)
}
foo_1(ansombe, x1 > 5)
```

I want this to get the same results as for `subset(ansombe, x1 > 5)`. Also, I want the same to work when the argument is passed on to a deeper level, i.e.

```
foo_2 <- function(x, mysubset) 
{  
  # some deparse, substitute etc. magic here ??
  foo_1(x, mysubset)
}
foo_2(ansombe, x1 > 5)
```

Here also I want the same result as above.

**What I have tried so far**

I tried a `substitute`-`deparse`, `eval`-`parse` combination, like

```
foo_1 <- function(x, mysubset)
{
  tx <- deparse(substitute(mysubset))
  subset(x, eval(parse(text=tx)))
}
foo_1(anscombe, x1 >5)
```

This is fine, but how do I go on for `foo_2` now?

Also, I remember the dictum by Thomas Lumley:

> If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question.
>   -- Thomas Lumley (R-help, February 2005)

So, I was wondering if there is a better approach than an `eval`-`parse` combination.?
Any ideas?

PS. This question is similar but does not include the deeper nesting: [Pass subset argument through a function to subset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880906/pass-subset-argument-through-a-function-to-subset)

PPS: Maybe it is fruitful applying the `.` function from `plyr`, but I don't know how...

Comment: I'm not a big fan of using `subset` when a simple `foo[foo[,1]<5,]` or similar construct will serve. If you can post some **small, reproducible** sample data we can show an easy way to do this.  EDIT: like BrodieG did :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you delay the evaulation as long as possible, something like this should work

```
foo_1 <- function(x, mysubset) 
{
  do.call("subset", list(quote(x), substitute(mysubset)))
}

foo_2 <- function(x, mysubset) 
{  
  do.call("foo_1", list(quote(x), substitute(mysubset)))
}

data(anscombe)
foo_1(anscombe, x1 > 5)    
foo_2(anscombe, x1 > 5)
```

but if you plan on mucking about with `mysubset` you would need to be more careful.It would help to know exactly why you are doing this.

Answer (score 4):

There might be dragons. (But those hide in `subset` too.)

```
foo_1 <- function(x, mysubset) 
{ 
  sub <- eval(substitute(mysubset), envir=x, enclos=parent.frame())
  x[sub,]
}

foo_1(iris, Sepal.Length == 5 & Species == "setosa")
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#5             5         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#8             5         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa
#26            5         3.0          1.6         0.2  setosa
#27            5         3.4          1.6         0.4  setosa
#36            5         3.2          1.2         0.2  setosa
#41            5         3.5          1.3         0.3  setosa
#44            5         3.5          1.6         0.6  setosa
#50            5         3.3          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

Comment: @BrodieG Hey, don't mess with us Targaryens.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can avoid `eval`, but you can avoid `parse`.  Just reconstruct the call to `subset` inside your function:

```
foo_1 <- function(x, mysubset) {
  eval(call("subset", x, substitute(mysubset)), parent.frame())
}
foo_1(mtcars, cyl == 6 & mpg > 20)
#                 mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4      21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
```