# Lazyeval in R -- How can I build a subset function?

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation

I'm trying to build a subset function in R that will accept dataframes as well as column names and running into issues using the lazyeval approach outlined [here](http://rpubs.com/hadley/lazyeval). Here's my code:

```
iris_fun <- function(df, selection_var, selection_input){

  temp <- subset(df, ~.data[[.env$selection_var]] == .env$selection_input)

  return(temp)

}
```

When I attempt to call this with:

```
iris_fun(iris, "Species", "setosa")
```

I get an error message:

> Error in subset.data.frame(df, ~.data[[.env$selection_var]] == selection_input) : 
>   'Subset' must be logical

Advice appreciated!

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. What are you trying to do, really?

Comment: @HongOoi, I'm trying to build a function that will subset a dataframe based on a given criteria (which will actually come from another dataframe). For now, I'm trying to get the first part to work -- subsetting based on a variable and value that will be inputs to the function (along with a dataframe).

Comment: in that example, hadley has redefined `subset` so it is no longer `base::subset`

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880906/pass-subset-argument-through-a-function-to-subset

Comment: @rawr you are 100% right -- thank you! My wheels were spending way too much time spinning.

Comment: It actually succeeds with version 0.1.10.9000 loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The R `subset` function is not designed for programming. This will do what you ask with none of the non-standard eval confusion:

```
iris_fun <- function(df, selection_var, selection_input){
                     df[ df[[selection_var]] == selection_input , ]}
```

(Unfortunately that article on "lazyeval" doesn't seem to be consistent with the package v 0.1.10. There's no `f_eval` or `f_interp`, so you cannot define the (lazy):subset-function. Need the devel-version.)